# What are the best dinner cruises in Sydney, offering a memorable dining experience with scenic waterfront views?

Tags: ferries, cruising, sydney, tourist-traps

What are the most scenic and popular routes for a Sydney dinner cruise, and what kind of dining experiences can passengers expect while enjoying the stunning harbor views?

Comment: Why do you quote mark? (So where did you found such sentence?). And avoid *best*: *best* is opinion based, and so we cannot answer such question. And *best* in travel means "tourist trap". Also "best" and "popular" is often contradictory. -- and no spam allowed here (I get a strange feeling).

Comment: Don't be strange, i usually quotes the Questions for Catchy, its ok i removed, and the tags naturally generated , not by me... i just added cruising only

Comment: The tags aren't "naturally generated". If you click the `edited x hours ago` text, you'll find it's a link that shows the entire edit history. This explains the "magic" of how those tags got there...

Comment: I’ve taken the public ferry to Parramatta just for shits and giggles, and it’s a nice little cruise. No dinner or anything, but you get to see a lot of different parts of the city for a ridiculously low price. You can also go towards Watsons Bay or Manly if you want to see more harbour and less river.

Comment: @aprilscott, your last edit brings the to be expected answers closer to spam, it does not help in reopening the question.

Answer (score 14):

As a Sydney resident, I can tell you that the dinner cruises are very touristy, and the food served on board will be thoroughly mediocre and overpriced.

[image: F4 ferry route map]

What I recommend to visitors instead is the public [F4 Pyrmont Bay ferry](https://transportnsw.info/routes/details/sydney-ferries/f4/090F4), which does a loop from Circular Quay to Darling Harbour and back.  It starts from central Sydney, passes by the Opera House, goes under the Harbour Bridge, past the bright lights of Luna Park, the shiny new skyscrapers of Barangaroo and deposits you in Pyrmont Bay next to the Maritime Museum and the Star Casino, all this for the princely sum of $6.43 (vs $100+ for the cruises).  Ferries run every 30 min or so and the views are particularly great at dusk when the lights are coming on.

There's no dining on board the public ferries, but there are countless options at both ends. Barangaroo in particular has a [string of lovely bayside restaurants](https://www.barangaroo.com/eat-drink) that, while not cheap, are not tourist traps and serve pretty good food, eg. love.fish and Muum Thai.  Cafe Sydney at the Customs House in Circular Quay is also stunning, but it's also pricey and needs to be booked well in advance.

Comment: Which all the cruises that passes this route? anyone mention?

Comment: (+1) The first paragraph is a description of pretty much any dinner cruise in any location globally

Comment: @aprilscott They run on more or less the same route, they even depart from the same piers in Barangaroo.